# cin отказывается работать

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, sublime-text-3, mingw

Только начал изучать с++, подключил mingw к sublime text 3, всё работало прекрасно до того момента пока я не попробовал что-либо ввести с клавиатуры, иначе говоря использование cin провоцирует бесконечный ввод в переменную, хотя с cout проблем не замечено, неймспейс прописан, надеюсь на помощь.

build system которую я использую, спастил у какого-то индуса, но это единственное, что работало, path прописан.

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",     
    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Вы бы лучше код привели...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как вы только начали изучение с++, то, наверное, вам не принципиально в какой IDE обучаться. Могу порекомендовать Codeblocks и Dev c++ для начала. В этих IDE у вас не должно возникнуть проблем, подобных описанной вами.